# Simple jQuery filter function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Problem explanation:** 
I have placed input elements around the DOM:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-filter="markets" data-cid="4" name="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" data-filter="categories" data-cid="30" name="checkbox">
```

When I check any of checkbox I should get JSON object like this:

*`{"categories":["4,5"],"markets":["30,31,32"]}`*

but I`m getting object like this:

```
{"categories":["30,31,32,4,5"],"markets":["30,31,32,4,5"]}
```

where **30,31,32** are markets but **4,5** is categories. Maybe someone can tell me, where is problem?

```
$(document).on('change',"input[name=checkbox]", function() {
    page = 0;
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        $this.addClass("checked");   
    } else {
        $this.removeClass("checked");
    }
    filter();
});

var filter = function() {
    var myObject = new Object(); 
    $('.checked').each(function(n) {            
        var objname = $(this).data('filter');

        arr = $('.checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).data('cid');
        }).get().join(",");

        if(arr.length > 0) {
            myObject[ objname ] = [ arr ];            
        }
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
    return JSON.stringify(myObject);
}

filter();
```

Comment: `.delegate` has been superseded by `.on`, so use `.on`

Comment: Only if the OP is using an up-to-date version of jQuery...

Comment: Why are you adding/removing a `checked` class? Just use the `:checked` selector.

Comment: Where exactly are you returning the string ?

Comment: The issue is that you just iterate back over every checked input when calling `.map()`, rather than just those ones that have that specific `data-filter` value. Arun's answer is a better way to do it, though you could also just change the selector in your code to: `arr = $('.checked[data-filter="' + objname + '"]')`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7Wg2r/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var filter = function () {
    var myObject = {};
    $('.checked').each(function (n) {
        var objname = $(this).data('filter');
        var array = myObject[objname] = myObject[objname] || [];
        array.push($(this).data('cid'))
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
    return JSON.stringify(myObject);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hk4NS/)